# Why cant i add this foreign key constraint?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Im frustrated. I cannot add the foreign key constraint for the table Test_info:

```
FOREIGN KEY Test_info(score) REFERENCES Test(score)
```

It keeps on giving me error 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint. I made sure the data type is the same, as well as names etc... anyone?

The entire SQL Table creation is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Employees    (
    ssn VARCHAR(20),
    union_mem_no VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (ssn)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Traffic_Control  (
    ssn VARCHAR(20),
    exam_date DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (ssn),
    FOREIGN KEY (ssn) REFERENCES Employees(ssn) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Technician   (
    ssn VARCHAR(20),
    T_name VARCHAR(20),
    phone_num VARCHAR(20),
    address VARCHAR(50),
    Salary INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ssn),
    FOREIGN KEY (ssn) REFERENCES Employees(ssn) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Model (
    model_no VARCHAR(20),
    Capacity INT,
    Weight INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (model_no)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Expert   (
    ssn VARCHAR(20),
    model_no VARCHAR(20),
    FOREIGN KEY (ssn) REFERENCES Technician(ssn) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (model_no) REFERENCES Model(model_no) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Plane (
    reg_no VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (reg_no)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Type (
    reg_no VARCHAR(20),
    model_no VARCHAR(20),
    FOREIGN KEY (reg_no) REFERENCES Plane(reg_no),
    FOREIGN KEY (model_no) REFERENCES Model(model_no)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test (
    FAA_no VARCHAR(20),
    T_name VARCHAR(20),
    score INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (FAA_no)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test_info    (
    ssn VARCHAR(20),
    FAA_no VARCHAR(20),
    T_date DATE NOT NULL,
    hours INT,
    score INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ssn, FAA_no),
    FOREIGN KEY (ssn) REFERENCES Employees(ssn) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (FAA_no) REFERENCES Test(FAA_no),
    FOREIGN KEY (score) REFERENCES Test(score)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: While not "the law", FK to PK is the norm and whatever it is has to be unique.  Not sure what you intend for this FK.  What's the idea here?

Comment: @LoztInSpace I was under the impression that a foreign key simply connects data from two tables. I should have known better that a foreign KEY is still a KEY. My bad. Thanks for the insight though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a UNIQUE constraint on the column you're referencing to be able to create a foreign key relation to that column.

However, from your data schema it looks like the `score` column would probably not have unique values.

Since you already established a foreign key relation with the `Test` table's primary key (`FAA_no`), I don't see the point of adding a second foreign key.

Comment: I dont think i understand what you mean.. Does a foreign key must reference a Primary key?

Comment: Doesn't have to be a primary key. Just has to be a column with a UNIQUE constraint.

Comment: Got it. Thanks! Learned something new.

Comment: @noobcoder It normally does reference a primary key, though. Since it's typically used to build one-to-many relationships between tables, the simplest way architecturally to do that is make a foreign key in a child table reference a primary key in a parent table.